# search field in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm trying to create a component with ng-select inside. Also I want to add a search field in dropdown:

```
<ng-select
  #mySelect
  [items]=[cars]
  [placeholder]="placeholder"
  >

  <ng-template ng-header-tmp>
    <span>My label</span>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template> Need search filed here</ng-template>

  <ng-template ng-option-temp>
      Some options
  </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

The search field display as option, but on first place. Is there some way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

simply you can add new input into the header template eg:

`<ng-template ng-header-tmp>
     <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchBtn" (ngModelChange)="changeSearchFn($event)"/>
  </ng-template>`

and filter the cars items when model change

see the full example here [Full Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-69xiog)

Comment: in my case I can have ng-header-tmp and also search field in dropdown, it will not be worked coz two ng-header-tmp are not allowed

Comment: no need for two ng-header-tmp just use one element and add both the search input and also the label with some styles into one header